How to prolink kotlin sourcecode from xcode - KPM
is any one of you able to help me with setup KMP mobile app?I sucessfully created KMP app. I have shared data model and rest api call. Everything is fine at Android studio and i can build iOS app too.
BUT. I cannot get working code prolinks to .kt sources. XCode opens shared.h file which is not readable. Is there any way to force XCode open source .kt file? For example - in xcode i command + click to class name "ApiManager" and xcode opens  "ApiManager.kt" not shared.h at ine with some unreadable objectiveC.
I use xcode-kotlin plugin. I have shared code imported into project.
Thank you
CocoaPods, XCFramewok, Regular framewor, googling for days

We make the xcode-kotlin plugin. Xcode isn't really an extendable ide, to put it mildly. Navigating from swift directly to kotlin (probably) wouldn't be possible. If you're debugging, if you step into a kotlin call, it may show you some non-source binary first, but continue stepping and it should wind up at kotlin source (I believe, but haven't tried that in a while)

But that makes KMP verry hard to use, isn't it?

¯_(ツ)_/¯ I guess? It's not as easy as fully integrated options, but it's a lot easier than writing two different sets of code. Like I said, Xcode only lets you do so much. I don't see it as all that difficult, but I've been doing this for a while. There are plenty of imperfect things in tech. I just spent a few days wrestling with various cloud providers to stand up a simple server, after AWS killed something that broke our production deploys. JetBrains is working on a combined editor, but Apple updates Xcode/Swift without concern for other vendors, so...
